# How to cast android Activity with CastRemoteDisplay on google cast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have just read about [RemoteDisplay](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote?hl=en) api from google chrome cast. I want to show view inside my Activity to my TV screen using chrome cast device. I try [this](https://github.com/googlecast/CastRemoteDisplay-android) sample from google. They are using [CastRemoteDisplayLocalService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplayLocalService) to show a [CastPresentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastPresentation) which is Dialog.

Here my use case is to show pdf to my chrome cast device and scroll and zoom this by mobile device.
I have shown the pdf on chrome cast successfully by adding pdfview inside CastPresentation. But it is not easy to control[Scroll, Zoom]. So it will be easy if I can show view inside my activity to cast like cast screen option does.

My first question is how can is show the view inside Activity to chrome cast?

My second question is remote cast use the Remote Display Receiver and my app have to cast videos and image also.So do i need to add two app in [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend CastPresentation which is very similar to an Activity but allows for off-screen rendering. You cannot remotely display an Activity using the Remote Display API. Most of what you can do in an Activity with regards to views, layouts and animation can be done in CastPresentation.

You can render both video and images using the same remote display receiver. The media player would be part of your CastPresentation view. Typically for video we recommend using an HTML receiver since that will not use the mobile device battery for longer content.

Comment: If I use two receiver i have to stop one receiver app when my user switch between pdf, video and images?

Comment: No use one receiver. You will have to dynamically handle displaying or playing the various kinds of content in your sender.

Comment: OK, So which should I use HTML receiver or RemoteDisplay? My app need to cast the Video, Photo and Pdf. I could not find any way to cast pdf with html receiver.

Comment: Please let me know any way we can cast pdf with html receiver

Comment: You will need a viewer that renders PDF. This is outside of the scope of the Remote Display API.

Comment: @LeonNicholls, in iOS, can I show only the app screen(view, I mean view in iOS) to TV. I don't wanna play audio/video/image. I need to share view only. Which API to use for IOS now? I see CastRemoteDisplay is only for Android in the documentation. Please help!